# Can anyone identify this uniform, the rank and if possible the date?

Tags: identification, uniform

Can anyone identify and date this image:

[image]

Comment: anything on the back?

Comment: Do you know anything about where the photo was taken?

Comment: Just to add he is wearing the Italian uniform model 1909.

Answer (score 8):

It looks to be a uniform of Italy's mountain warfare troops, the [Alpini](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpini), likely from around WWI.

It's hard to get an exact year but the photo itself certainly looks like other WWI photos, and the coat looks much more like the WWI-era uniform (such as the images below) than the WWII-era version that [these reenactors are wearing](http://www.ww2italianreenactment.com/m40uni.html).

As for the rank, the [cappello alpini](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cappello_Alpino) he's wearing would have more info, but I can't make out much detail. The feather doesn't look like a fully black raven's feather, so he might be some sort of officer since, [depending on rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cappello_Alpino#Rank_insignia), officers wore brown eagle or white goose feathers.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Nasty nasty fighting in the region in WWI as well https://www.smithsonianmag.com/history/most-treacherous-battle-world-war-i-italian-mountains-180959076/  "An estimated 600,000 Italians and 400,000 Austrians would die on the Italian Front"  Sadly that's how boys get to be Captains.

Answer (score 0):

He was an Alpino, italian mountain's troop, the uniform is that of the WW1,
and he was a private, nor NCO sleeve chevrons or officers stars and V shaped chevrons on the felt hat. The fishbone shaped puttes are tipical of the time of war, the crow feather on the Alpine felt hat   was eliminated for reasons of war until the end of 1917, but this is a study photo, it may have been put back for the occasion.